# jquery template - output to textarea (or: converting jquery object to string)

Tags: jquery, string, templates, dom, jquery-templates

I'm writing a tool that will generate HTML based on JSON data, and puts the output in a textarea for easy copy/paste. I am using jquery templates for generating the HTML but I'm having trouble putting the result in the textarea, because .tmpl() returns a jQuery object (collection of DOM elements).

EDIT:

After testing with a simpler version, I found that $("#HtmlPageTemplate").tmpl().html(); does work. So the problem lies with the actual template. Any suggestions on making the following template work?

```
<script id="HtmlPageTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
        <head>
           <title>API - ${ObjectName}</title>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/meyer-reset.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/google-code-prettify/src/prettify.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/api-documentation.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
           <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js">{{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
           <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js">{{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
           <script src="scripts/google-code-prettify/src/prettify.js">{{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
           <script>
               $(function(){
                   if ("onhashchange" in window) { // event supported?
                       window.onhashchange = function () {
                           SelectTabByAnchor(window.location.hash);
                       }
                   }
                   else { // event not supported:
                       var storedHash = window.location.hash;
                       window.setInterval(function () {
                           if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
                               storedHash = window.location.hash;
                               SelectTabByAnchor(storedHash);
                           }
                       }, 100);
                   }

                   function SelectTabByAnchor(anchor){
                       var tab = -1;

                       if(anchor.substr(0, 10) == "#Property-"){
                           tab = 0;
                       }
                       else if(anchor.substr(0, 8) == "#Method-"){
                           tab = 1; 
                       }
                       else if(anchor.substr(0, 7) == "#Event-"){
                           tab = 2;
                       }

                       if(tab > -1){
                           $("#PropertiesMethodsEventsContainer").tabs("select", tab);
                           //window.location.href = window.location.hash;
                           window.location.hash = window.location.hash;
                       }
                   }

                   $("a").click(function(event){
                       var anchor = $(this).attr("href");
                       SelectTabByAnchor(anchor);
                       // Stop the .Item event from showing/hiding the details
                       event.stopPropagation();
                   });

                   $(".Item").click(function(){
                       $(this).next().toggle();
                   }).hover(function(){
                       $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
                   },
                   function(){
                       $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
                   });

                   prettyPrint();
                   $("#PropertiesMethodsEventsContainer").tabs();

                   if(window.location.hash){
                       //SelectTabByAnchor(window.location.hash);
                       $("a[href=\"" + window.location.hash + "\"]:first").trigger("click");
                   }

               });
               {{html "</sc"+"ript>"}}
        </head>
        <body>
            {{tmpl "#ClassTemplate"}}
        </body>
        </html>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably like to display the actual generated HTML (if that's what you're generating). Anyway. By using `.html()` you can always access HTML string of any jQuery object. Hence you can easily do this to get the jQuery object in your text area:

```
$("#textareaID").val($("#templateID").tmpl(objToUse).html());
```

This should put generated HTML inside your `textarea`.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHW3R/) proves it works as expected. Document ready functionality is at the end of the script block (which is rather long since I had to add jQuery `.tmpl()` plugin). But it only does what I've written above. It only sets text area value based on generated template HTML.

The problem you may be having that this technique returns **the content of the jQuery element** which may in you case be empty. If this is the case, than use this code to get whole generated code template instead:

```
$("#TimingTemplate").tmpl().wrap("<div></div>").parent().html();
```

Comment: This is what I first tried. $("#HtmlPageTemplate").tmpl().html(); returns null, even though $("#HtmlPageTemplate").tmpl() does return a valid jQuery object.

Comment: @Brett: I just tried it and it works. Let me put together an example.

Comment: @Brett: Check my edited answer with added link to a working example. So I suppose you most likely have a problem with your template.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I tested with a simpler version and it does appear to be a problem with the template... Editted question. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brett: Can you check the solution I added to my answer? I'm not really sure whether it'll work in your case, since you're having a complete HTML document as your template, but it may still work...

Comment: @Brett: I've simplified your template and whenever I add a script to it it doesn't get included in the result. I suggest you start by adding elements to your template. One by one and see when you bump into a problem. That should lead you to the final solution.